# Can't find length of Dataframe Error: Float object can't be called

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I have a Pandas Dataframe and I am trying to find the length of said data frame to split it in half. However when using the code

`half_df = len(df) // 2`
I get the error: TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

I can't seem to get my head around the problem. Shouldn't the Pandas data frame be a Dataframe and not a float type ?

Complete code below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')
df

    Symbol  Description Category2   Category3   GICS Sector Market cap  Dividend yield  Price to TTM earnings   Price to TTM sales  Price to book value Action
0   AAPL    Apple Inc   Common stocks   Large cap   Information Technology  $2,381,445,264,600  0.61%   23.36   6.17    35.33   Analyze
1   MSFT    Microsoft Corp  Common stocks   Large cap   Information Technology  $1,842,074,858,614  1.00%   25.42   9.57    11.31   Analyze
2   GOOG    Alphabet Inc Class C    Common stocks   Large cap   Communication Services  $1,164,555,710,000  0.00%   7.90    4.31    2.32    Analyze
....

half_df = len(df) // 2

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-e20afcd61c48> in <module>
----> 1 half_df = len(xrz) // 2

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have redefined the builtin `len()` function, assigning the name `len` to a float. That is, you must have done something like this earlier in your code:

```
len = 5.0
```

When you later write `len(df)`, Python tries to call the float that has been assigned to `len`, but floats are not callable, and so it raises an Exception.

This sort of bug is why it's a good idea to avoid re-defining builtins like `len`. A linter like [pylint](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/) can help find such oversights.

Comment: The only other time in my code I am using Len is in this for loop: "for i, len in enumerate (data['%Percentage']):
        
        if data['%Percentage'][i] > 0:"

Comment: Would the problem arise from this ? because other than the for loop I am not using Len.

Comment: After rearranging the code blocks I can confirm that the problem arose from the usage for i, len in enumerate I am not quite sure why but after removing this loop the code ran fine

Comment: loop variables in Python remain in scope after the loop completes (try running something like `for x in range(1): pass; print(x)`), so yes, that would cause this issue (as you found). Regardless, better to choose a different name for the loop variable. (What if you decided you wanted to call `len()` within the loop?) One convention in such cases is to add a trailing underscore: `for i, len_ in ....`

Comment: That is indeed interesting. I was under the impression that len was a "global" variable which always gets the length of an element without being able to be reassigned. In case of my for loop would something like variable_length = len(df) for I, variable_len in enumerate work as well ?

Comment: `len()` is actually a function, see `https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len`. It takes an object as argument and returns its length (implemented on custom objects with the `__len__` method)

Comment: Concerning your question about the for loop, I'm not sure I understand---I think there is maybe a typo and in any case Python is inherently hard to understand without line breaks. But you can always try it out in the interpreter and see what happens :)